# A single word describing a piece of literature that contains many figures of speech

Tags: single-word-requests, figures-of-speech

I'm looking for a positive word. A word that describes a writer and/or a piece of their work... which has the quality of being densely packed with impressive uses of literary devices.

Example sentence:

1. He tends to like authors that are ..........
2. He only appreciates songs if the lyrics are .........

The word I'm looking for doesn't necessarily have to be applicable to both the sentences above. Either one will do. A single word is ideal, but a short phrase would be acceptable.

Once again, I wish to reiterate that I'm looking for a positive word. I realize that this style of writing has its critics and there are words which could be used to attack its over-the-top nature. But I want to describe it as a good thing. So anything with primarily negative connotations is out.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say *literary devices*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [elaborate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elaborate) would fit:

> 2: marked by complexity, fullness of detail, or ornateness
>   *elaborate* prose

A related word is [ornate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ornate):

> 1: marked by elaborate [rhetoric (2b)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rhetoric) or [florid (1b)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/florid) style
>
> 2: elaborately or excessively decorated

<sub>(sources: Merriam Webster)</sub>

Comment: Ooh. I like this one. But I like `ornate` even better! You'll have my upvote soon.

Comment: Yeah, ornate would work as well; you should probably post it as a separate answer.

Comment: I got the word from your definition. You should be the one who gets credit :)

Answer (score 1):

You should consider ***flowery***.

> He only appreciates songs if the lyrics are ***flowery***.

ODO:

> **[flowery](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/flowery)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1.2** (of speech or writing) full of elaborate or literary words and phrases.
>   ‘flowery prose’
>
> ‘Kabary, the flowery speeches given at all formal, ancestral occasions in the central highlands, are recognized as requiring great skill.’

Comment: I won't deny it's a fine choice, (+1), but this is the kind of word I had in mind when I said no negative connotations. This word is used way too often to put something down.

Comment: @TusharRaj unfortunately, all synonyms listed have that negative feel (even if slightly). I personally use this word positively. I guess the context gives it the positive or negative ring or may be it's just me. That person in the example sounds like me and certainly I'd take it positively.